# Resolver for a particular dependency

Tags: sbt

How can I configure build to specify that particular dependency should be sought in a specific repository, and all other dependencies should not? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [explicit URL](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL) via `from` method for a particular dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += 
  "slinky" % "slinky" % "2.1" from "https://slinky2.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.1/slinky.jar"
```

Comment: Does it bring transitive dependencies too? Or it just downloads jar file from give url without checking pom file?

Comment: I don't know, but I would expect it to resolve transitive dependencies separately and download them from any available repository. If you want to override the order of resolvers or limit them to a certain list, it's also possible, but it's a different use case.